# Why is my CUDA kernel (Numba) behaving differently on successive calls with same inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, cuda, gpu, race-condition, numba

I have a noob bug in numba + cuda in python. Numba version is 0.51, CUDA version is 10.2. The code below gives very different outputs when called repeatedly with the exactly same inputs.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda, jit

@cuda.jit()
def writeToArray(vec, array_in, array_out):
    ''' vec is a 3x1 vector, array_in is a 3D array, array_out is a 3D array of the shape of array in'''
    i,j,k = cuda.grid(3)
    value = array_in[i,j,k] * vec[0] + array_in[i,j,k] * vec[0] + array_in[i,j,k] * vec[0]
    cuda.atomic.max(array_out,(i,j,k), value)
    # cuda.synchronize()

def test():
    
    threadsperblock = (8,8,8)
    blockspergrid_x = ( 17 + threadsperblock[0]) // threadsperblock[0]
    blockspergrid_y = ( 21 + threadsperblock[1]) // threadsperblock[1]
    blockspergrid_z = ( 5 + threadsperblock[2]) // threadsperblock[2]
    blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y, blockspergrid_z)
    array_in = np.random.rand(17,21,5).astype(np.float_)
    vec = np.array([1.0, -1.0, 1.0]).astype(np.float_)
    d_array_in = cuda.to_device(array_in)
    d_vec = cuda.to_device(vec)
    while True:
        array_out_1 = -999.999*np.ones_like(array_in)
        array_out_2 = -999.999*np.ones_like(array_in)
        d_array_out_1= cuda.to_device(array_out_2)
        d_array_out_2 = cuda.to_device(array_out_2)
        writeToArray[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](d_vec, d_array_in, d_array_out_1)
        writeToArray[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](d_vec, d_array_in, d_array_out_2)
        array_out_1_host = d_array_out_1.copy_to_host()
        array_out_2_host = d_array_out_2.copy_to_host()
        assert(np.allclose(array_out_1_host, array_out_2_host))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

This should not break but eventually, after a about 10 iterations of the while loop, the assertion fails. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel code is making illegal, out-of-bounds accesses.  When you size the grid this way:

```
blockspergrid_x = ( 17 + threadsperblock[0]) // threadsperblock[0]
blockspergrid_y = ( 21 + threadsperblock[1]) // threadsperblock[1]
blockspergrid_z = ( 5 + threadsperblock[2]) // threadsperblock[2]
```

you run the possibility of creating "extra" threads.  Those are threads whose i,j,k indices are outside the "shape" of your input array.  You don't want these threads to act.  The usual approach is to put a "thread check" in your kernel code:

```
$ cat t31.py
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda, jit

@cuda.jit()
def writeToArray(vec, array_in, array_out):
    ''' vec is a 3x1 vector, array_in is a 3D array, array_out is a 3D array of the shape of array in'''
    i,j,k = cuda.grid(3)
    if i < array_in.shape[0] and j < array_in.shape[1] and k < array_in.shape[2]:
        value = array_in[i,j,k] * vec[0] + array_in[i,j,k] * vec[0] + array_in[i,j,k] * vec[0]
        cuda.atomic.max(array_out,(i,j,k), value)
    # cuda.synchronize()

def test():

    threadsperblock = (8,8,8)
    blockspergrid_x = ( 17 + threadsperblock[0] -1) // threadsperblock[0]
    blockspergrid_y = ( 21 + threadsperblock[1] -1) // threadsperblock[1]
    blockspergrid_z = (  5 + threadsperblock[2] -1) // threadsperblock[2]
    blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y, blockspergrid_z)
    array_in = np.random.rand(17,21,5).astype(np.float_)
    vec = np.array([1.0, -1.0, 1.0]).astype(np.float_)
    d_array_in = cuda.to_device(array_in)
    d_vec = cuda.to_device(vec)
    i=0
    while i<20:
        array_out_1 = -999.999*np.ones_like(array_in)
        array_out_2 = -999.999*np.ones_like(array_in)
        d_array_out_1= cuda.to_device(array_out_2)
        d_array_out_2 = cuda.to_device(array_out_2)
        writeToArray[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](d_vec, d_array_in, d_array_out_1)
        writeToArray[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](d_vec, d_array_in, d_array_out_2)
        array_out_1_host = d_array_out_1.copy_to_host()
        array_out_2_host = d_array_out_2.copy_to_host()
        assert(np.allclose(array_out_1_host, array_out_2_host))
        i+=1
        print(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
$ cuda-memcheck python t31.py
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note the use of `cuda-memcheck` above.  You can use it in a similar fashion with your original code to see the out-of-bounds error messages.  Out of bounds access like this will result in a failed CUDA context, meaning every kernel launch (and all other CUDA activity) after the first fails, doing nothing at all.

I'm not suggesting testing for exact floating point equality will work in all possible scenarios, but it seems to work for this particular case.  You might wish to read [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html).